# Rails - Strong params, and creating a new resource via nested attributes for a delegated association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

My Rails 4 app is a fundraising tool for a bike ride. A user can create a RiderReg(istration), and a User also has an associated MailingAddress, that is delegated to the User via the RiderReg.

The associations seem to work in the console, but I'm getting thrown by strong params, and the controller won't accept nested attributes for a RiderReg's MailingAddress -- because the MailingAddress is associated with the User.

You may wonder - Why are Users and Riders separate models? Because Users can be donors and/or riders -- but all users whether riders or no will need addresses.

ANYHOO -- let me add some code examples.

```
class RiderReg < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :rider, :class_name => "User"
    delegate :first_name, :last_name, :title, :full_name, :receipts, :mailing_address, to: :rider, allow_nil: true, prefix: false


  # accepts_nested throws an error - but how else to allow for strong params?
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :mailing_address
end

 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :rider_reg, :foreign_key => :rider_id

  has_one :mailing_address, :as => :addressable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :mailing_address
end

class RiderRegsController < ApplicationController
    private 

    def rider_reg_params
    params.require(:rider_reg).permit(:ride_option, :primary_phone, :secondary_phone, :birthdate, :goal, :bio, :accept_terms, :photo, :mailing_address_attributes => [:line1, :line2, :city, :state, :zip])
  end
end
```

My Params hash submit via form_helper looks like this:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"PbDQe/f4S+dlhroY+ZDVh6MS0Mmo0fUr88UiE4OJJQQ=", "rider_reg"=>{"ride_option"=>"Original Track", "mailing_address"=>{"line1"=>"asdfasfd", "line2"=>"", "city"=>"asdfsadf", "state"=>"Alaska", "zip"=>""}, "primary_phone"=>"", "secondary_phone"=>"", "bio"=>"", "goal"=>"0.0"}, "rider_reg_month"=>"1", "rider_reg_year"=>"1934", "rider_reg_day"=>"1", "commit"=>"Create Rider reg"}
```

and my server log tells me this:

```
Unpermitted parameters: mailing_address
```

So -- after a couple of days of headbanging - I think it may be time to admit my ignorance here. Any advice is much appreciated!
thanks!

Comment: There's no Rider model - just a RiderReg and User model. User is aliased as rider when referenced through RiderReg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because there is no association between RiderReg and MailingAddress.

There are two ways you can go around this.

1. Add a relationship between `RiderReg` and `MailingAddress`
2. Switch the `RiderReg` and `rider` relationship and foreign key. Then accept nested attributes for `rider` and have the view as something like:

   ```
   = f.fields_for :rider do |uf|
     # user fields here.
     = uf.fields_for :mailing_address do |maf|
       # mailing address fields here
   ```

Then adjust your strong params to also accept a user.

Comment: THANK YOU! this works -- sadly my reputation is not high enough that I can upvote your answer... but thanks for the assistance, and I'll circle back and upvote when I fill out my stack overflow creds a bit more.

Comment: To delve a little deeper. Nested Params will not be passed as `*_attributes` unless is has a relationship.